# How to merge two rows having same data?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i have a table with some data i want to merge the identical row 
i.e.as shown in image two identical rows having same tDateWorked,empid,jobid
i want to merge this records so that OT and ST should appears in same line.

[image]

Comment: What attempts have you have so far? Are you looking to update the table with these values, and delete the "extra" rows, or just return the data you want ub a `SELECT`?

Comment: i am fetching this data from table.i want to store merged data in table..so they look like what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select tDateWorked, empId, craftCodeId, jobId,
       sum(ot) as ot, sum(st) as st
from t
group by tDateWorked, empId, craftCodeId, jobId;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only numeric amounts in OT, ST, just try this:

```
SELECT
  tDateWorked, empid, jobid, SUM(OT) AS OT, SUM(ST) AS ST
FROM
  Table
GROUP BY
  tDateWorked, empid, jobid
```